# Why I do not get a full page datatable in flexdashboard?

Tags: css, r, flexdashboard

I am trying to get a full page display of data in flexdashboard. I have followed one of the stackoverflow suggestions yet cannot find the link, will add the code here:

```
<style>
.dataTables_scrollBody {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

but given the links to a solution from a different website. This is where the solution is: https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-css-to-flexdashboard-with-runtime-shiny/69307/2

Now, I have added a style.css file in www folder. And then added a reference to the style css . This is how:

```
 ---
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: simplex
    vertical_layout: scroll
    css: www/style.css
    orientation: rows
    source_code: embed

---
```

Yet, it did not correct it. There is so much space left down the page. Here is a picture:

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: Try setting the css property to be `height: 100%;`. Otherwise without additional sample code, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Marcus it doesn't do the job.

Comment: In the yaml params change this `vertical_layout: scroll` to `vertical_layout: fill`. You can also set the vertical layout per page. Untested since there's no reprex.

Comment: @Jamie it worked but then it messed up my data viz.

Comment: @Gab - using fill will change the structure some. You'll get more help if you provide some sample code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I'll reiterate that the lack of reprex makes this hard, but it looks like you might be using the dt package to render the table. In that case you'd need to add the paging argument:
`renderDT({datatable( df, options = list(paging = FALSE))})`